# How to get upper bounds in Enumerable.Range

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get the upper bounds in linqs enumerable range for example:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(x => "index: " + x + " Max: ").ToList();
```

The list should have:

```
index: 0 Max: 3
index: 1 Max: 3
index: 2 Max: 3
...
```

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(x => "index: " + x + " Max: " + 3).ToList();` since you already know `3` :)

Comment: Note; `3` is *not* the "upper bound" or the "max" - it is the *count*...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, not exactly. Your lambda function will always be execute in the scope of the instance.

You can do something like this:

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(0, 3);
range.Select(x => "index: " + x + " Max: " + range.Max()).ToList();
```

But then you might as well do this:

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(0, 3);
var max = range.Max();
range.Select(x => "index: " + x + " Max: " + max).ToList();
```

BTW, since the range you used starts at zero (`[ 0, 1, 2 ]`) the max will be 2, not 3. Did you want the `.Count()` instead, or no?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The input of `Select` could be any sequence, and it might not have an upper bound at all (well, obviously the value can't be more than `Int32.MaxValue`, but other than that, there's no way to know).

In you case, since the arguments to `Enumerable.Range` are hard-coded, obviously you can deduce the max value, which is `start + count - 1 = 2`. Note that 3 is the *count*, not the max value; it happens to be the exclusive upper bound, but only because the start value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(0, 3);
var max = range.Max();
var s = range.Select(x => string.Format("Index: {0}, Max: {1}", x, max));
```